# What are good strategies for graphing large datasets (1M +)?

Tags: javascript, redis, elasticsearch, d3.js

I'm just starting to approach this problem, I want to to allow users to arbitrarily select ranges and filters that allow them to graph large data sets (realistically it should never be more than 10 million data points) on a web page. I use elasticsearch as the method of storing and aggregating the data, along with redis for keeping track of summary data, and [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) is my graphing library.

My thoughts on the best solution is to have precalculated summaries in different groupings that can be used to graph from. So if the data points exist over several years, I can have groupings by month and day (which I would be doing anyway), but then by groupings of say half day, quarter day, hour, half hour, etc. And then before I query for graph data I do a quick calculation to see which of these groupings will give me some ideal number of data points (say 1000).

Is this a reasonable way to approach the problem? Is there a better way?

Comment: 10M points? Do people do that? :shocked:

Comment: I would run some tests to see what impact graphing 10M points will have on your server, database, and throughput in general. Users do not have to be able to do anything they desire if it will severely impact the performance of the system for everyone else. Test, and if it slows things down, then set a cap on the number they can select. It's a defensive tactic to avoid DOSing your own site.

Comment: I don't see any reason to make that many data points available since it is so far beyond the ability of a screen to display them?  I will obviously have DOS in mind, but if I am basically only serving a few K data points on a few M request, it becomes much less of an issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reconsider the amount of data...

1. Even in desktop plotting apps it is uncommon to show that many points per plot - e.g. origin prints a warning that it will show only a subset for performance reasons. you could for example throw away every 3rd point to make them less.
2. You should give the user the ability to zoom in or navigate around to explore the data, like pagination alike style ...
3. Grouping or faceting how it is called in Lucene community is of course possible with that many documents but be sure you have enough RAM+CPU

Answer (score 0):

You can't graph (typically) more points than you have dots on your screen. So to graph 1M points you'd need a really good monitor.